# Mysql docker container - can't get much of anything to work

Tags: mysql, docker, networking

I'm trying to use the [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) to do some database development.  I can't seem to connect to it, nor use its client to connect to an existing database.

## Server

Here's me trying to create a database and connect to it:

```
% cat Dockerfile
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY drupal.sql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY civicrm.sql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN perl -pi -e 's/^#(bind-address\s*=\s*127\.0\.0\.1)/$1/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

% docker build -t my-mysql .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.166MB
Step 1/4 : FROM mysql:5.7
 ---> e1e1680ac726
Step 2/4 : COPY drupal.sql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93d57dcd45e9
Step 3/4 : COPY civicrm.sql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cb0342af9523
Step 4/4 : RUN perl -pi -e 's/^#(bind-address\s*=\s*127\.0\.0\.1)/$1/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf68cb50c994
Successfully built bf68cb50c994
Successfully tagged my-mysql:latest

% docker run -p 4306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d my-mysql
ff19571bebf58ac1d58e44d40677c693953cd981fd70d18fd93d3d2fe8738349

% mysql --port 4306 -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p1234
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

It is actually finding *something* at that port, because if I connect to some random port with no server on it, there's a different error:

```
% mysql --port 4307 -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p1234
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

The logs do seem to show the server starting up successfully:

```
% docker logs ff19571bebf5 2>&1 |tail -n3
2019-10-22T01:04:51.953141Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2019-10-22T01:04:52.933930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191022  1:04:52
```

## Client

Similarly, when I try to use the container as a client to connect to a local mysql server, the client can't connect.  Here's connecting using a local client:

```
% mysql -u ken -p -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3306
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 253
Server version: 5.7.27 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

and here's trying the same thing using the Docker client:

```
% docker run -it --network=host --rm mysql mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3306 -u ken
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is this a problem of not understanding Docker networking, or is something wrong with these images?

## Eventually

Eventually I do want to get this working using docker-compose, so that my web container can talk to my database container, but I thought I'd simplify this down to something easier to debug.

Comment: Could you include your dockerfile too?

Comment: @kkkkkkk that's the first part of my first example, where I do `cat Dockerfile`.

Comment: You need to export port 3306 from the container using `EXPOSE 3306`

Comment: Adding `EXPOSE 3306` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I just found this paragraph at https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ , maybe that's the cause of my second problem?
"The `host` networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."  I'm on a Mac using Docker Desktop 2.1.0.3.

Comment: Try accessing directly from your host machine rather than accessing from the inside another container. As when you are inside another container, `127.0.0.1` is not the address to the db container.

Comment: @kkkkkkk I wasn't trying to access from another container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a server process inside a Docker container to bind to 127.0.0.1, that is *that container's* localhost interface, and it will be unreachable from outside the container.  The `mysql` image's default is correct here; delete the `RUN` line that changes the MySQL `bind-address` setting.

Comment: This works if I run the image `mysql:5.7` directly, but not a derived image with data loaded.  I'll update the question to show an example.

Comment: Actually, I think I'm wrong.  If I bind to `0.0.0.0` (all networks) then I can get connections to work (but I didn't realize it because I have to wait quite a while for the DB to initialize).  Same if I remove the binding line altogether, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering Howto Eventually get this working using docker-compose.

you want to do this first , to get  docker-compose working, even if you do not need swarm.

```
docker swarm init
```

setup a docker-compose.yml file looks like this

```
version: "2"
networks:
    mynet:
        driver: overlay
services:
    web:
        image:  put image tag here
        hostname:  web
        ports:
            - "8000:80/tcp"
        networks:
           mynet:
                aliases:
                     - web
    db:
        image:  put mysql image tag here
        hostname:  db
        ports:
              - "4306:3306/tcp"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
        networks:
           mynet:
                aliases:
                     - db
```

**check indentation** before firing docker-compose . I typed above text on a handset and any editing help is appreciated.

in the directory where you put the docker-compose.yml,  say it is "mydir" for  example.

```
docker-compose up
```

docker-compose will try to create a new nerwork named "mydir_mynet" , and two containers named "web" and "db" respectively.
after docker-compose finish launching you should be able to

```
mysql --port 4306 -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p1234
```

or mysql client inside docker

```
docker exec db mysql --port 3306 -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p1234
```

pay attention to the difference in port number

bring down the containers and the network by

```
docker-compose down
```

Comment: binding to 0.0.0.0. inside container is suggested, reason in the answer  by@davidmaze

Comment: Thanks a ton!  What's the reason for initializing `swarm` before doing the `docker-compose` stuff?

Comment: docker-compose would not able to setup networks if the node is not  in a swarm. I did not dig further .PS: As in development need, when docker-compose encourage  you to use ```docker stack deploy``` , ignore it .  I tried and wasted half a day, stacking pushes everything to the ```swarm``` way,  not  friendly for development, for example , not able to set container name in swarm, and  mem_limit causes lot of trouble in swarm.